# Add a file path into a formula that is typed into a another cell vlookup

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

How to use vlookup when I have a command button which inserts file path in a cell @`Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(5, 4).Value = Get_Path` while another command button uses the file in that path mentioned for vlookup formula. @`ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],'Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(5, 4).Value'!C1:C2,2,0)"`

the complete code is as below. your advises are valuable. thanks in advance.

```
Sub currentZOE3()
'declare variable to store path

Dim Get_Path As String

    Dim fileExplorer As FileDialog
    Set fileExplorer = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    'To allow or disable to multi select
    fileExplorer.AllowMultiSelect = False

    With fileExplorer

If .Show <> 0 Then
Get_Path = .SelectedItems(1)
End If
Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(3, 4).Value = Get_Path

End With

End Sub
Sub lastweekZOE3()

'declare variable to store path

Dim Get_Path As String

    Dim fileExplorer As FileDialog
    Set fileExplorer = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    'To allow or disable to multi select
    fileExplorer.AllowMultiSelect = False

    With fileExplorer

If .Show <> 0 Then
Get_Path = .SelectedItems(1)
End If
Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(5, 4).Value = Get_Path

End With

End Sub

Sub Macro4()
'
' Macro4 Macro
'

'

Dim updWb As Workbook
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Set updWb = Workbooks.Open(Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(3, 4).Value)
Set DSheet = updWb.Sheets("Sheet1")

Cells.Select
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .Size = 10
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
    End With
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    With Selection.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent4
        .TintAndShade = 0.399975585192419
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 5
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 6
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 7
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 8
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 9
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 10
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 11
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 12
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 13
    Columns("N:N").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("N1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
'
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 5
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 6
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 7
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 8
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 9
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 10
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 11
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 12
    Columns("Q:S").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Range("Q1") = "Concantenate"
    Range("R1") = "Delivery Plan"
    Range("S1") = "Last Week Comments"
    Range("Q2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-16]&RC[-9]&RC[-7]"
    Range("S2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2]," & Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(5, 4).Value & "!C1:C2,2,0)"
    Range("R2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFS(RC22=""YBWR"",""What"",ISNUMBER(RC25),""Fully Delivered"",RC19=""Billable Only"",""BILLABLE ONLY"",AND(ISBLANK(RC25),NOT(ISBLANK(RC27))),""Under shipment"",AND(ISBLANK(RC25),ISBLANK(RC27),ISNUMBER(RC14)),""Under packing"",AND(ISBLANK(RC25),ISBLANK(RC27),ISBLANK(RC14)),TEXT(WEEKNUM(RC23),""W00""))"
    Range("P3").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Range("Q8833:S8833").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    Selection.FillDown
    Cells.Select
    Range("Q8833").Activate
    Selection.Columns.AutoFit

    With Cells
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
      "=($R1=""What"")"
    With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
        .SetFirstPriority
        With .Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 12173758
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        StopIfTrue = False
    End With
     End With

     With Cells
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
      "=($R1=""Fully Delivered"")"
    With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
        .SetFirstPriority
        With .Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 5691552
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        StopIfTrue = False
    End With
     End With

     With Cells
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
      "=($R1=""under shipment"")"
    With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
        .SetFirstPriority
        With .Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 3774674
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        StopIfTrue = False
    End With
     End With

     With Cells
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
      "=($R1=""under packing"")"
    With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
        .SetFirstPriority
        With .Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 15793920
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        StopIfTrue = False
    End With
     End With

    Sheets(Array("Sheet2", "Sheet3")).Select
    Sheets("Sheet3").Activate
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete

        Range("A1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:= _
        Range("A1:A8837"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
        :=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$BE$8837").AutoFilter Field:=1

    'Declare Variables
Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim pvtfield As PivotField

On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("PivotTable").Delete
Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotTable"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set PSheet = Worksheets("PivotTable")
Set DSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")

'Define Data Range
LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)


'Define Pivot Cache
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), _
TableName:="PivotTable")

'Insert Blank Pivot Table
Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="PivotTable")

'Insert Row Fields
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Sold to name")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 1
End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Sales Document")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 2
End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Customer purchase order number")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 3
End With

'Insert Column Fields
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Delivery Plan")
.Orientation = xlColumnField
.Position = 1
End With

'Insert Data Field
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("SO Net value")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Position = 1
.Function = xlSum
.NumberFormat = "#,##0"
.Name = " Sum SO Net value "
End With

'classic and expand/collapse button removal

Range("C7").Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable")
        .InGridDropZones = True
        .RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow
    End With
    Range("B4").Select

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").ShowDrillIndicators = False
```

'Format Pivot
TableActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").ShowTableStyleRowStripes = TrueActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleMedium9"

End Sub

Comment: It should work to change this: `"=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],'Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(5, 4).Value'!C1:C2,2,0)"` to `"=VLOOKUP(RC[-2]," & Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(5, 4).Value & "!C1:C2,2,0)"`. You can string parts of a formula together with the `&` character, and use `"` characters to define whether you are working within the formula or VBA code.

Comment: I have made changes but it still wants me to manually pick the file. please refer my latest edit.

Answer (score 0):

An external reference must consist of the full file name, including path if the workbook isn't open. It must be placed between square brackets and surrounded by single quotes that include the worksheet's name.
`VLOOKUP(RC[-2],'[My Workbook]Sheet1'!C1:C2,2,0)`

Therefore this is the syntax for adding your dynamic workbook to your Vlookup formula.

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 ="=VLOOKUP(RC[-2], " & "'[" & INDIRECT(ADDRESS(5,4,1,1,"Sheet1")) & "]" & INDIRECT(ADDRESS(5,4,1,1,"Sheet1")) & "'!C1:C2,2,0)"
```

Sorry, I couldn't test this formula but feel reasonably confident that it will work. Of course, the address you provided for path and sheet names is identical and therefore impossible. Please change the definition of the ADDRESS function to fit the reality.

Comment: i have the path for a excel file in cell D5 of my current workbook which im running the macro.

Comment: We may be talking past each other. Every VLOOKUP needs a lookup range. If the range is in another worksheet, the formula must indicate the sheet by name. If the range is in another workbook the formula must indicate the workbook by name. If the workbook isn't open the name must include the path. Therefore, since you are talking of a "Path" I assume you are talking about a lookup range in an external workbook. Therefore you should have one cell for the path and another for the sheet. My solution provides for that.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment (which is almost correct) you will need & characters to insert the reference into your formula. The correct syntax to use is:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],'" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(5, 4).Text & "'!C1:C2,2,0)"
```

Please note, this will still result in a prompt asking you what sheet to use from your referred workbook.